# hyperlink in the Angular App requires #! instead of just #

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

To navigate between the routes using the anchor tag if i specify the path as below it does not work-

```
<a href="#/link1">Go to link1</a>
```

Instead if i specify below path it works

```
<a href="#!/link1">Go to link1</a>
```

using AngularJS 1.6.1 version. Browser IE 11.0. Why this behavior? I have used previsouly AngularJS 1.2 -1.3 version, but did not get this issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some transformation on url with $urlRouterProvider.rule in your config function like below:

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.path(),
        normalized = path.replace('!/', '');
        if (path !== normalized) {
            return normalized;
        }
});
```

You could follow the following links,

[`Angular force an undesired exclamation mark in url`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455077/angular-force-an-undesired-exclamation-mark-in-url/41223197#41223197)

[`angular url is adding unwanted characters`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110941/angular-url-is-adding-unwanted-characters)

Comment: thanks @Sajeetharan, but why i need to do that? this is not the default behavior of Angular.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455077/angular-force-an-undesired-exclamation-mark-in-url/41223197#41223197